# Using Okta with WSO2

Tags: wso2, okta, wso2-identity-server

I have been unsuccessful at finding any documentation around utilizing Okta with WSO2 API manager. All documentation I find online is to utilize WSO2 Identity services as the IDP for other WSO2 products. I believe there is a way to add an external IDP, but again I haven't found it. And I attempted to add the Identity Provider in the WSO API Manager dashboard and placed some values with my Okta instance but have had zero luck.

Any docs? 
Any articles? 
Does this functionality even exist?

Thanks!
-Michael

Comment: Were you able to finally use Okta as identify provider and login to WSO2 using Okta?

Answer (score 0):

API manager has a component called "Key Manager", which is the component responsible for Authentication and Authorization and of users as well as issuance/validation of OAuth tokens. Please refer [External Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager) for more information.

API manager has internal "Key Manager", out of the box, and can connect most of the other OAuth key managers.